# Hardware Specification for Nominatim Installation (Local Openstreet Server)

Tags: virtual-machine, openstreetmap, nominatim

I am planning to install openstreet server on my Ubuntu Linux machine and following this tutorial [link](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation). I came across their hardware requirement:

> Hardware
>
> A minimum of 1GB of RAM is required or installation will fail. For a
>   full planet import 32GB or more are recommended.
>
> For a full planet install you will need about 500GB of hard disk space
>   (as of Mai 2015, take into account that the OSM database is growing
>   fast). SSD disks will help considerably to speed up import and
>   queries.

I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find anywhere that we can filter our data by country.

Question 1: Currently I am dealing with just US related addresses and want to filter out the data. Could anyone tell me how can just import the addresses related to US.

Question 2: Is there any Open street VM already available which we can use? and just import the data?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting a very high volume of calls? Otherwise, you could just use the API on OSMs own nominatim  server. It's not just the memory and data sizes, but the job of keeping it all current is quite demanding too.

Comment: Yes I am expecting high volume of calls and I have to geocode like 2 million addresses. I am not sure why people have down voted my question. I have gone through the whole documentation and everything.

Comment: Because stackoverflow is about programming and your question isn't. There are various other stackexchange sites available, for example http://gis.stackexchange.com and http://serverfault.com.

Regarding the question: If you just import the US then you will need less disk space of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not very clear on what data you are using to populate Nominatim.

If you wish to use OpenStreetMap, instead of using the whole "planet" file you can use a USA extract of the data from a provider such as Geofabrik. This is mentioned in the instructions. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Import_and_index_OSM_data

If you are using your own data for Nominatim, you should just import the USA data you have into Nominatim.

When referring to "OpenStreetMap" this can be the data, the project (of people gathering and improving the data), or it can refer to the community. In a software context, there is a lot of OpenStreetMap systems, some of which has been created for and continues to only serve the OpenStreetMap project. There are often alternatives for every OpenStreetMap-related software/system. For this reason I don't think there are many VMs available, people have different needs with regards to what they want in an OpenStreetMap stack.

Comment: Could you suggest me something regarding the problem I am facing here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945993/permission-denied-when-installing-openstreetmap-server). I feel like like stuck here so any suggestion is welcome.